# I am unable to find the id to this button so it makes it unclickable to me how do I press it?

Tags: python, selenium

I dont know how to click a button in selenium without the id can anyone help me?  I have already tried the class but it wont work.

[image]

Comment: could be hidden. one workaround is to use `tab` key and make selenium press tab in a loop until the button ir reached (for that You have to count how many times You have to press the tab key to land on it)

Comment: @Matiiss what do you mean use tab key?

Comment: on Your keyboard there is key named 'Tab'. simulate the press of that key in your browser

Comment: I know what the tab key is but I dont get what you mean how will a tab work and how do I go through the whole code tabbing?  I know how to loop but what will a loop of tabs do?

Comment: when You are in a browser (or pretty much anywhere else) what does the tab do? it focuses on different elements. so if You press it enough times the focus will be on the button You want and then You simulate enter press and the button will be clicked

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks I got it!

Comment: How did you try the class? Show us.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `id`. You need to use other locator. For example css selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            ".btn.btn-secondary.btn-lg.btn-block")
```

Also, wait for this element to be clickable before clicking it.
Check my other answers

Answer (score 0):

you can use any attribute , as there is an data attribute use that :

Xpath:

```
//button[@data-track="Sign In"]
```

CSS:

```
button[data-track="Sign In"]
```

You can also use :

```
//button[contains(text(),"Sign In")]
```

sytax for xpath or css is :

xpath:

```
//tagname[@attribute="value"]
```

css:

```
tagname[attribute="value"]
```

so you can check for any attribute and its value. not only id